# Summing values from an iterated function in order to average the total

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, iteration, pi

My code is as follows.

```
import random
times_to_repeat = 10**6
circle_radius = 1
times_to_iterate = 100

def in_circle(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2 < circle_radius**2

def pi_approximator():
    points_in_circle = 0
    for a in range(times_to_repeat):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        if in_circle(x, y):
            points_in_circle += 1
    pi_approx = (points_in_circle / times_to_repeat) * 4
    print(pi_approx)

def pi_iterator():
    for b in range(times_to_iterate):
        pi_calculator()

pi_iterator()
```

The purpose is to create an approximation of pi using randomly generated points around a circle.

I've got that down, but I'm trying to make it more precise by iterating the function many times and then averaging it out.

I've found plenty of information on how to sum up a list that you make manually, but I'm having difficulty finding any information on how to add the values from a function together.

My desired output would be to take the values from `pi_iterated()`, add them all together, and divide them by `times_to_iterate` in order to get the average approximate value of `pi` over all of my iterations.

I've tried a few things, but they have mostly just been shots in the dark and all have failed so I didn't see any point in including them with my code.

I can supply people with the failed attempts I've made if they need it though.

Comment: shouldn't `pi_calculator` be `pi_approximator`?

Answer (score 0):

In pi_approx calculation use float to get the correct value and you have to save the value rather than just printing. So you can return it and store it in a list. Average of that list gives will be your desired output

```
def pi_approximator():
    ...
    ...
    pi_approx = (float(points_in_circle) / times_to_repeat) * 4
    return (pi_approx)

def pi_iterator():
    result = []
    for b in range(times_to_iterate):
        result.append(pi_approximator())
    print float(sum(result))/len(result)
pi_iterator()
```

Comment: The question is tagged python-3.x, so there is no need for the `float` in there